# Как посмотреть информацию о процессе с помощью файловой системы proc?

Tags: linux

Как посмотреть информацию о процессе с помощью файловой системы proc, зная id процесса?

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос, какую конкретно информацию ? Собственно где искать ее вы уже сами и ответили в папке /proc/pid-процесса. Остается видимо выбрать из нужных файлов в этом каталоге нужные данные

Answer (score 4, accepted):

практически половину ответа вы написали в вопросе.

да, можно посмотреть содержимое различных файлов в каталоге `/proc/идентификатор-процесса`.

смысл файлов/каталогов и их содержимого объясняется, например, в [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), или в документации к программе *linux*: [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)